# SVG ClipPath Text Updates in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, svg

I'm using an SVG clip path to dynamically change a number on my site, and while it works beautifully in Firefox, it doesn't work in Chrome.

I'm using state.rating in two places - once in the svg text and once at the bottom in a p tag.  Clicking anywhere in the outer div adds one to the rating.  This works perfectly in Firefox, and the SVG text updates along with the p tag.

In Chrome, however, it doesn't change the value.  I have found that if I resize the window even slightly, the text will update to the correct number.

Is this just something that Chrome hates?

```
class SmallRating extends React.Component {
  state = {
    rating: 1
  }

  addOne = () =>{
    this.setState({rating: this.state.rating + 1})
  }

render(){
  return (
      <div className="ratingBox" onClick={this.addOne}>
        <svg style={{width: 0, height: 0}}>
          <clipPath id="ratingSVGQuality">
            <text className="smallSVGText" y="72">{this.state.rating}</text>
          </clipPath>
        </svg>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div className="QualityNumber">
            </div>
          </div>
          <p>{this.state.rating}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  )}
}
```

Comment: If you think you've found a Chrome bug, report it to Chrome's bugtracker.

Comment: Thanks Robert - I really just wanted to make sure it wasn't me!  I've submitted the bug as per your suggestion.

Thanks again!